# React Ionic v7.1 - IonRouterOutlet dynamic and static route

Tags: reactjs, ionic-framework, react-router, react-router-dom

How to combine dynamic and static route with the same depth? Ionic with React

Tried:

1:

```
<IonRouterOutlet>
   <Route path='/:category' render={() => <CategoryPage/>} exact={true} />
   <Route path='/login' render={() => <LoginPage />} exact={true} />
</IonRouterOutlet>
```

2:

```
<IonRouterOutlet>
   <Route path='/login' render={() => <LoginPage />} exact={true} />
   <Route path='/:category' render={() => <CategoryPage />} exact={true} />
</IonRouterOutlet>
```

3:

```
<IonRouterOutlet>
 <Switch>
   <Route path='/login' render={() => <LoginPage />} exact={true} />
   <Route path='/:category' render={() => <CategoryPage />} exact={true} />
 </Switch>
</IonRouterOutlet>
```

Only **3:** works as expected, but then when changing pages it reloads it, without animation and pre-reserved page

**2:** Always go to dynamic Route (/:category CategoryPage) (example: /login opens CategoryPage)

**1:** Works as expected when you load **/login** (initially).
But when you initially load (example: **/test-category**), you cannot go to /login anymore, it always go to dynamic route /:category (CategoryPage)

I tried to add Regex (negation) /:category(^((?!login).)*$) any tried other, but didn't find solution with regex

*- also tried all combination with and without exact*

package.json

```
"@ionic/pwa-elements": "^3.1.1",
"@ionic/react": "^7.1.0",
"@ionic/react-router": "^7.1.0",

"react": "^18.2.0",
"react-dom": "^18.2.0",
"react-router-dom": "^5.3.4",
...
```